How to handle and convert datatypes in model development in Python?
I am working on a timeseries model and running into an issue with the datatypes. The code below gives me an error TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'. When I call the model variable it runs into the issue. The norm variable is an object, this is following the codebase here https://github.com/marcopeix/time-series-analysis/blob/master/TSMixer.ipynb
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def res_block(inputs, ff_dim):

  norm = layers.BatchNormalization
  print(norm(axis=[-2, -1]))
  print(inputs)

  # Time mixing
  x = norm(axis=[-2, -1])(inputs)
  x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # [Batch, Channel, Input Length]
  x = layers.Dense(x.shape[-1], activation='relu')(x)
  x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # [Batch, Input Length, Channel]
  x = layers.Dropout(0.7)(x)
  res = x + inputs

  # Feature mixing
  x = norm(axis=[-2, -1])(res)
  x = layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation='relu')(x)  # [Batch, Input Length, FF_Dim]
  x = layers.Dropout(0.7)(x)
  x = layers.Dense(inputs.shape[-1])(x)  # [Batch, Input Length, Channel]
  x = layers.Dropout(0.7)(x)
  return x + res

def build_model(
    input_shape,
    pred_len,
    n_block,
    ff_dim,
    target_slice,
):

  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = inputs  # [Batch, Input Length, Channel]
  for _ in range(n_block):
    x = res_block(x, ff_dim)

  if target_slice:
    x = x[:, :, target_slice]

  # Temporal projection
  x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # [Batch, Channel, Input Length]
  x = layers.Dense(pred_len)(x)  # [Batch, Channel, Output Length]
  outputs = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # [Batch, Output Length, Channel])

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model = build_model(
    input_shape=(512, data_loader.n_feature),
    pred_len=96,
    n_block=8,
    ff_dim=64,
    target_slice=data_loader.target_slice
)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 1
----> 1 model = build_model(
      2     input_shape=(512, data_loader.n_feature),
      3     pred_len=96,
      4     n_block=8,
      5     ff_dim=64,
      6     target_slice=data_loader.target_slice
      7 )

Cell In[59], line 12
     10 x = inputs  # [Batch, Input Length, Channel]
     11 for _ in range(n_block):
---> 12   x = res_block(x, ff_dim)
     14 if target_slice:
     15   x = x[:, :, target_slice]

Cell In[58], line 6
      3 def res_block(inputs, ff_dim):
      5   norm = layers.BatchNormalization
----> 6   print(norm(axis=[-2, -1]))
      7   print(inputs)
      9   # Time mixing

File ~/miniconda/envs/tadpole_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py:144, in BatchNormalization.__init__(self, axis, momentum, epsilon, center, scale, beta_initializer, gamma_initializer, moving_mean_initializer, moving_variance_initializer, beta_regularizer, gamma_regularizer, beta_constraint, gamma_constraint, synchronized, **kwargs)
    125 def __init__(
    126     self,
    127     axis=-1,
   (...)
    141     **kwargs,
    142 ):
    143     super().__init__(**kwargs)
--> 144     self.axis = int(axis)
    146     if synchronized and backend.backend() != "tensorflow":
    147         raise ValueError(
    148             "Argument synchronized=True is only supported "
    149             "with the TensorFlow backend."
    150         )

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'


What're you expecting norm(axis=[-2, -1]) to do? The axis argument cannot be a list https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization#args

How can I handle it to still work in the script?
